# What is the purpose of the T-568 ethernet color code standard

Tags: ethernet

A question came into mind. as i was crimping some ethernet cables at home.

I am talking about straight cable not crossover cables.

What is the true reason for the T-568A or T-568B color standard. Because just arranging the wire in sequence will work just fine as long as the wire is connected  on the same pin on the other end, arranging them in sequence will also give a cleaner crimp.

[image]

in the image ont T568A blue is sandwich between the orange ? why is that?

Is it to reduce noise ?

if so how will it affect on different category? cat 5, 5e, 6, 7, and 8

Comment: There are situations where you might need to work on a termination without access to the other end of the cable.

Comment: yes, what i meant was why did the TIA standard not make the standard make it in a sequence in the first place, since most of the time they are in a twisted pair and beside each other. I have edited the post to include a picture for reference

Comment: `arranging the wire in sequence will work just fine as long as the wire is connected on the same pin on the other end` ... that is  absolutely incorrect .... ethernet uses specific pins for its data pairs .... those pins have to be connected to twisted pairs of wire .... if you do not have a twisted pair for the data transfer then the cable will not work correctly ....  you may get a connection, but it will most likely be very, very slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments you clarified,

> what i meant was why did the TIA standard not make the standard make it in a sequence in the first place, since most of the time they are in a twisted pair and beside each other.

This keeps the pin assignments compatible with the telephone [modular connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector) that it's derived from.

With this arrangement, a cable can be repurposed from voice use to data without re-terminating it. The blue pair can even be used for voice while the orange and green pairs are used for 10 or 100 Mbps Ethernet in the same cable.

Comment: So basically it is because of legacy devices using that color scheme and was brought over and there is no other technical reason behind it ?

Comment: That is correct +1 audio line 1 was centre pair line 2 next outer pair but poor for high speed data so they changed it but then it is the cable that makes most of the difference so the jack/plug being only a couple cm makes little difference for 100mbps but does matter on 1Gbps So if you had T568A R/J you need the cable paired to match the A wiring.

Comment: @Jack, Presumably the Bell System guy who designed it had some kind of reason (compatibility of 4P connectors with 6P connectors, etc.) But I don't know enough about it to give a definitive answer. The people designing twisted-pair ethernet were looking for a lower-cost alternative to coax, so it makes sense they'd design to use existing products rather than something new.

Comment: I can settle for that answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> Because just arranging the wire in sequence will work just fine as long as the wire is connected on the same pin on the other end, arranging them in sequence will also give a cleaner crimp.

Well … no. You have to keep the pairs intact. You may switch the orange pair with the blue one or the green one or the brown one, but not which pins belong to the same pair.

That's because both wires of a pair are connected to the leads of a tiny transformer per pair inside the socket (or close behind it). If you connect the wrong wires, those become unbalanced and susceptible to EMI and crosstalk.